# ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED when deploy to IIS 7.5 when using IIS manager user

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, msdeploy, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I'm trying to deploy from a teamcity server to my iis server but I get unauthorized when I use an IIS Manager user set up in IIS. If I use a Windows account it works just fine. Am I missing something?

I thought it was enough to create an IIS Manager User in ISS, or do I have to add that user to the domain or server I'm trying to deploy to?

In the Management Service Delegation I have added two rules, it could probably be combined into one. The first rule is for contentPath and iisApp and the second is for createApp. Both rules are run as an administrator user. I have added that all users (*) are allowed to execute the rule.

Is it something else I need to enable on the target server for it to work with IIS Manager Users?

I get the following message in my event viewer:

```
IISWMSVC_AUTHORIZATION_SERVER_NOT_ALLOWED

Only Windows Administrators are allowed to connect using a server connection. 
Other users should use the 'Connect To Site or Application' task to be able to connect.

Process:WMSvc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've been looking for an answer for some time and couldn't find it... but of course I figure it out myself as soon as I post the question here. The answer to my problem was that I have to add the IIS Manager User to the site which I want to deploy to. So if I selected the sites and then opened up the "IIS Manager Permissions" and added my user it all started working just as expected.

Comment: Any idea why I can only deploy using the server admin credentials and not the IIS user? Both are in the IIS Manager Permissions

Comment: I'm not sure. Does the user that the IIS rules you have configured rights to write to the folder where you want to deploy? You might also need access to modify the applicationhost.config file do do the deploy.